# Joomla 1.7 Global News Module language override

Tags: module, overriding

I need help changing the modules text "View More Publications...." to "View More Articles..."

I am not a css guru by any means. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I am running (reluctantly) Joomla 1.7

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you are using, I'm guessing English, so look for 
/languages/en-GB folder and look for the .ini file you think has the text string you're looking to change.

The easiest way to find it would be to download the folder, then search the whole folder for the string using Notepad++ / Dreamweaver / your favorite text editor.

Once you find the string / file, simply make the change you want, and upload the file.

I'm not including any text override instructions, as I'm guessing you're not going to be upgrading this soon.